# Custom Placeholder Labels

Tags: sxa

I am trying to create a page design with a header, footer, and three containers in the "main" section for different kinds of content.

I'd like to somehow label these placeholders so that it's immediately obvious to the `Content Editor` what each section is for. I am almost certain I had done this before when I was experimenting, but nothing I try seems to be working.

[image]

I tried to create new `Placeholder Settings` for each section in the hope that the name of the Placeholder Settings would rename that section, but that did not work (I thought this was how I'd done it in the past).

It seems as if the label is based off of `placeholder key`, but I'm not sure how to change that - and even if I could, I have a feeling that I shouldn't - but maybe I can assign a display name to the placeholder key?

SXA 1.8.1

Sitecore 9.1.1

---

EDIT: Here is a video of the process that I am following when I attempt to do this, as per Peter's answer, could this be a bug? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJZzfrAzPA8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add Container to your page or Partial Design, it will look like this:

[image]

Click inside of container to configure container inside:

[image]

Click on the `Edit` button (1). In wizard, click `Create New Settings` (2), specify custom name (3) and choose where you would like to create these settings (4). If you choose `Data`, Placeholder Settings will be created locally under Data item under current item. If you choose Placeholder Settings, it will be created under current site.
Specify `Allowed controls / renderings` if you wish (6) by hitting `Edit` button (5).
If you wish to limit components that are allowed in that Container, this is the way to go.

[image]

And Container / Placeholder has custom name now :

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter,

Thank you for your help, this is the process that I have been following in my initial attempts, so I suspect that maybe there may be a bug in 1.8.1 or 9.1.1 preventing this from happening? I have uploaded a video here of me going through the process, so you can see the issue from my end. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJZzfrAzPA8

Comment: And if you use local Data folder instead? Also try to do this directly on page. Does it make any difference?

Comment: BTW I used Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8 so could be in your version there is a bug

Comment: Tested directly on the page (both with local & site data folder) and with local data folder on the partial, none of them allow me to rename the placeholder as you have done above. So I think it is safe to assume there is likely a bug, as this is a fresh install of SXA

Comment: Seems like a valid assumption. Create support ticket for Sitecore Support

Comment: This bug has been raised with Sitecore